# 'create-large-nodes' and 'name suffix=-large' options does not working in nicematrix latex package

Tags: nicematrix

I have been using `create-large-nodes` `nicematrix` environment option combined with `name suffix=-large`, which is used like to `tikz` option,  inside of `code-after` `nicematrix` option, like in [nicematrix package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf). But it is returning the follow error message:

> ​! Package pgf Error: No shape named nm-1-1-1-large-large is known.

It seems those `nicematrix`'s options does not working correctly. Does anybody know what is happening?

The MWE follows below.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}


\begin{small}           
    \begingroup
    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \begin{align}
        \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}^{i} = & %
        \begin{bNiceArray}{CCCCCC}[%
        create-large-nodes, 
        margin,
        extra-margin=2pt,
        code-after={\tikz[name suffix=-large]{\node (a) at (1-4) {$a$};}},
        ]
        \Block{3-3}{\tikz{\node(FAlephNode){$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}_{\boldsymbol{\aleph}}^{i}$};}}  &  &           & \mathtt{f}_{1\,(\varpi+1)}          & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\eta} %
        \\
        &  &           & \vdots                              & \vdots & \vdots               %  
        \\
        &  &           & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,(\varpi+1)}     & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\eta} %
        \\
        \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,1} & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,(\varpi+1)} & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\eta} %
        \\
        \vdots                     & \vdots & \vdots                          & \vdots                              & \ddots & \vdots               %
        \\
        \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,1}       & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\varpi}       & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,(\varpi+1)}       & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\eta} %
        \end{bNiceArray}%
        \label{eq:someequation}
    \end{align}
    \endgroup
\end{small}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I have ever used aforementioned code without `create-large-nodes` and `code-after` options, and it works fine. But it does not perform what I want.

Comment: Your code compiles without error for me. Have you the latest version of `nicematrix`? Moreover, I don't understand where you want to put the `a` with your instruction in the `code-after`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny, yes, I guess. I downloaded the version released on January 22th 2020 on last tuesday. About letter `a`, it is just a test.

Comment: @F.Pantigny, my intention is creating four submatrix into of this bNIceArray, and afterward I would want attaching an overbrace on the first submatrix. But, I read in documentation that nest nicematrix is not allowed. To work aound this, I had thought using a `code-after`, together with `create-large-nodes`, to make some adjust. Besides, I could make a border around first submatrix, and putting it into overbrace. But, in both options, I guess I have to sove this problem. Do you have some idea of how I can make it?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question but I think you should modify your initial question (in this site, the questions and the answers are meant to be easily readable and potentially usefull for all the readers, thus creating a kind of knowledge base).

Comment: @F.Pantigny, I followed your suggestion. I created the issue [How can I put overbraces on an amount of selected columns (or rows) in nicematrix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527247/155670). This one is related to put overbrace on matrix. I would like to ask to you transfering your below answer to that issue, adjusting your solution according to the issue statement. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem cause of this issue: my MikTeX was outdated. After updating, this code worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The block created in the cell `1-1` by the command `\Block` has the name `1-1` for `nicematrix` (this is not explicitly said in the documentation of `nicematrix`: I will probably change that).

So, you can add a brace over that block by using it (we don't need the 'large nodes'):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{small}           
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}^{i} = & %
\begin{bNiceArray}{CCCCCC}[%
margin,
extra-margin=2pt,
code-after = 
     { \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw [decorate,decoration = brace]
              ([yshift=1.5mm]1-1.north west) to  
              ([yshift=1.5mm]1-1.north east) ;
       \end{tikzpicture} } ]
\Block{3-3}{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}_{\boldsymbol{\aleph}}^{i}}  &  & & \mathtt{f}_{1\,(\varpi+1)} & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\eta} %
\\
&  &           & \vdots                              & \vdots & \vdots               %  
\\
&  &           & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,(\varpi+1)}     & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\eta} %
\\
\mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,1} & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,(\varpi+1)} & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\eta} %
\\
\vdots                     & \vdots & \vdots                          & \vdots                              & \ddots & \vdots               %
\\
\mathtt{f}_{\eta\,1}       & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\varpi}       & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,(\varpi+1)}       & \cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\eta} %
\end{bNiceArray}%
\end{align}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]