# How can I put overbraces on an amount of selected columns (or rows) in nicematrix?

Tags: nicematrix

I would like to highlight block of matrix, which is formed by its first 3 lines and columns. In order to make it, I was thinking to put an overbrace on 3 first columns, like this figure:

[image: Exemple of how I want my matrix]

But I would also like to specify for which columns or rows I will expand overbrace of matrix outside. How can I do it using nicematrix package? Below, it follows the basic MWE to make the matrix that I want.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}



\begin{document}


\begin{small}           
%   \begin{subequations}
        \begingroup
        \allowdisplaybreaks
        \begin{gather}
            \begin{aligned} 
                \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}^{i} & = %
                \begingroup
                    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[%
                    margin,
                    nullify-dots,
                    ]
                        \mathtt{f}_{1\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{1\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots & & \Vdots %  
                        \\
                        \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \noalign{\kern2mm}
                        \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \Vdots & & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots %
                        \\
                        \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\eta} %
                    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
                \endgroup%  
            \end{aligned}   
        \end{gather}
        \endgroup
%   \end{subequations}
\end{small}


\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430681/197451

Comment: @jsbibra, your suggestion is interesting, because it gave me an insight that how I put other decorations in nicematrix using tikz. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `code-after` hook to add the brace.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}           
%   \begin{subequations}
        \begingroup
        \allowdisplaybreaks
        \begin{gather}
            \begin{aligned} 
                \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}^{i} & = %
                \begingroup
                    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[%
                    margin,
                    nullify-dots,
                    code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}[
                        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,raise=2pt}]
                    \draw[decorate,thick] (1-1.north west) -- (1-3.north east)
                    node[midway,above=1.5ex]{$\scriptstyle\mathcal{F}_N^i$};
                    \end{tikzpicture}}
                    ]
                        \mathtt{f}_{1\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{1\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots & & \Vdots %  
                        \\
                        \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \noalign{\kern2mm}
                        \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \Vdots & & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots %
                        \\
                        \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\eta} %
                    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
                \endgroup%  
            \end{aligned}   
        \end{gather}
        \endgroup
%   \end{subequations}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to also add the pmatrix braces as in your screen shot, you can do the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\tikzset{block matrix/.style={path picture={
\draw ([xshift=#1,yshift=\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.south west)
 -| ([xshift=\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.north west)
  -- ++ (#1-\pgflinewidth/2,0)
  ([xshift=-#1,yshift=\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.south east)
 -| ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.north east)
  -- ++ (-#1+\pgflinewidth/2,0);
}},block matrix/.default=0.8ex}
\begin{document}

\begin{small}           
%   \begin{subequations}
        \begingroup
        \allowdisplaybreaks
        \begin{gather}
            \begin{aligned} 
                \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}^{i} & = %
                \begingroup
                    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[%
                    margin,
                    nullify-dots,
                    code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}[
                        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,raise=2pt}]
                    \node[inner xsep=1ex,fit=(1-1) (3-3),block matrix,thick](block){};
                    \draw[decorate,thick] (block.north west) -- (block.north east)
                    node[midway,above=1.5ex]{$\scriptstyle\mathcal{F}_N^i$};
                    \end{tikzpicture}}
                    ]
                        \mathtt{f}_{1\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{1\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{1\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots & & \Vdots %  
                        \\
                        \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\varpi\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \noalign{\kern2mm}
                        \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{(\varpi+1)\,\eta} %
                        \\
                        \Vdots & & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots %
                        \\
                        \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,1} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\varpi} & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \mathtt{f}_{\eta\,\eta} %
                    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
                \endgroup%  
            \end{aligned}   
        \end{gather}
        \endgroup
%   \end{subequations}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. It is exactly what I want. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The version 6.4 of `nicematrix` (2021/11/23) provides new commands `\OverBrace` and `\UnderBrace` available in the `\CodeAfter` to address that kind of situation. The braces are braces of standard LaTeX (that is to say constructed with the current mathematical font) and not braces of Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}           
\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\ff}{\mathtt{f}}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}^{i} = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin,nullify-dots]
    \ff_{1\,1} & \Cdots & \ff_{1\,\varpi} & \ff_{1\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \ff_{1\,\eta} \\
    \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots & & \Vdots \\
    \ff_{\varpi\,1} & \Cdots & \ff_{\varpi\,\varpi} & \ff_{\varpi\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \ff_{\varpi\,\eta} \\
    \noalign{\kern2mm}
    \ff_{(\varpi+1)\,1} & \Cdots & \ff_{(\varpi+1)\,\varpi} & \ff_{(\varpi+1)\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \ff_{(\varpi+1)\,\eta} \\
    \Vdots & & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
    \ff_{\eta\,1} & \Cdots & \ff_{\eta\,\varpi} & \ff_{\eta\,(\varpi+1)} & \Cdots & \ff_{\eta\,\eta} 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{1-1}{3-3}][slim,extra-height=-1mm,xshift=1mm]
  \OverBrace{1-1}{3-3}{\scriptstyle\mathcal{F}_N^i}[shorten,yshift=1mm]
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]